fillMaxWidth() not working when using it in childrens of scrollable horizontal containers
fillMaxWidth with a value of 0.5f is not working, instead, is wrapping to the content width.
Here is the children, which is inside a LazyRow:
OutlinedButton(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f)

How can I use fillMaxWidth() when using scrollable horizontal containers?
I achieved it using this:
OutlinedButton(
        modifier = modifier.width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp * buttonWidthPercentage)

but I hope there is a better way to do it

Finally solved it by a simpler way:
modifier = modifier.width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp * buttonWidthPercentage)

The solution proposed by Jan Bína didn't work as I'm setting the modifier width in a button but not in a LazyColumn item

The thing is that the fillMaxWidth function makes the element fill the full width of the parent container, while LazyRow has an infinite width. I don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to do. If you want the element to take up the entire screen, then instead of LazyRow it's better to use HorizontalPager.
val myList = remember { mutableStateListOf<MyItem>() }
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 1)
    
HorizontalPager(
    pageCount = myList.size,
    state = pagerState
) { page ->
    Text(myList[page].name)
}

data class MyItem(
    val name: String
)


By default fillMaxWidth returns minWidth/maxWidth as same value from Constraints coming from parent or previous Modifiers. When parent is scrollable or on of the previous Modifiers is scroll maxConstraints becomes Constraints.Infinity while minWidth is same. maxWidth also can be changed Modifier.layout{} as well.
Basically Composable measurement range becomes minWidth-Constraints.Infinity with fillMaxWidth. constraints.hasBoundedWidth checks for infinite maxWidth, and because of that composable can be measured in a range that contains their widths and they are assigned with width as big as their content.
You can read more about Constraints and size modifiers in this link.
The snippet below belongs to node of fillMaxWdith/Height
private class FillNode(
    var direction: Direction,
    var fraction: Float
) : LayoutModifierNode, Modifier.Node() {
    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        val minWidth: Int
        val maxWidth: Int
        if (constraints.hasBoundedWidth && direction != Direction.Vertical) {
            val width = (constraints.maxWidth * fraction).fastRoundToInt()
                .coerceIn(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth)
            minWidth = width
            maxWidth = width
        } else {
            minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

  // ... Rest of the node of fillMaxWidth/Height modifier

Your approach is correct, you can also get maxWidth from a BoxWithConstraints, especially useful with paddings, and spaces used by other Composables or Modifiers, if you wrap your LazyRow it. Then using 0.5*maxWidth you can set measurement range, or simply speaking width, for your items in HorizontalRow.
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {

        val itemWidth = maxWidth * .5f

        LazyRow {
            items(5) {
                OutlinedButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(itemWidth),
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Another link for explaining how size modifiers work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79012092/5457853

There is a special modifier that works like fillMaxWidth, but in a LazyRow, it's fillParentMaxWidth(fraction: Float). From its documentation:

Regular Modifier.fillMaxWidth can't work inside the scrolling horizontally layouts as the items are measured with Constraints.Infinity as the constraints for the main axis.

